# How to set the path of an input file in Console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am facing a problem in setting the path of input ".txt" file. I am reading the contents of the file and modifying the contents. So how can I set the path so that it will work for any computer(if someone will simply paste the project and try to run it.)

I have tried following options.

```
1) var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\input.txt";
2) var path = "input.txt";
```

But I am getting a run time DirectoryNotFound exception.  For

```
var path = @"D:\Projects\Demo Project\C#\Problem1\Problem1\input.txt" ;
```

It is working fine. But it will work only for this directory structure.

I need something like:- ResolveUrl("~/input.txt"); So that it will work for every case.

Comment: when do you get that excepcion?

Comment: What folder do you ideally want to use?  The user's Documents folder?

Comment: Thanks JotaBe.
FileStream inputFile = new FileStream(INPUT_FILE_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
In this line.

Comment: Is that working path inside your web site root? and the one not working outside?

Comment: Thansk Steve. My console application path is "D:\Projects\Demo Project\C#\Problem1\Problem1" . I want to give reference from the project root folder.

Comment: I'm confused now. You tag the question as console-application and asp.net. Which one is the right one?

Comment: Sorry.:( It is a console application.

Comment: If you want to get the directory where your assembly dll resides, then @CoDeaDDict's answer is what you're looking for.  However, just make sure that the user under which your assembly is executed has permission to read/write to that folder.  If you want to use a location where you are more likely to always have access, I would look at Isolated Storage, or the temp folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Combine that with `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` if all you want is the directory.

if you working in a website, as the comments on question shows, you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

Comment: Can not I provide path reference from current project root directory like ResolveUrl("~/input.text") ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
```

to get the directory the app started in.

Just remember to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` if it's a console app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the directory where your application is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```